# D3 - Enter(), Exit(), Update() function doesnt work correctly

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I want to be able to adjust the data of my D3 chart and update the chart. To do this, I tried to delete the old "slice" elements and then update them.

My problem is that the wrong "slices" elements are deleted (not the missing ones) and the same, that are delete will be opened again (picture, green should be delete and red will be deleted). I want the "g", "path" and "text" elements to be deleted in "g.slice" and then the new elements will be created with the new data. My delete and update code will be find in the "Enter(), Update, Exit()" comment section.

[image]

```js
 // Data
            const data1 = {
            "name": "TOPICS",
            "children": [{
                "name": "Topic A",
                "children": [{
                "name": "Sub A1",
                "size": 4
                }, {
                "name": "Sub A2",
                "size": 4
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "Topic B",
                "children": [{
                "name": "Sub B1",
                "size": 3
                }, {
                "name": "Sub B2",
                "size": 3
                }, {
                "name": "Sub B3",
                "size": 3
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "Topic C",
                "children": [{
                "name": "Sub A3",
                "size": 4
                }, {
                "name": "Sub A4",
                "size": 4
                }]
            }]
            };

            const data2 = {
            "name": "TOPICS",
            "children": [{
                "name": "Topic A",
                "children": [{
                "name": "Sub A1",
                "size": 4
                }, {
                "name": "Sub A2",
                "size": 4
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "Topic B",
                "children": [{
                "name": "Sub B1",
                "size": 3
                }, {
                "name": "Sub B2",
                "size": 3
                }, {
                "name": "Sub B3",
                "size": 3
                }]
            }]
            };

            //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------            
            // Declare variables
            let i_region_static_id = "sunburst",
            parentDiv = document.getElementById(i_region_static_id),
            width = parentDiv.clientWidth,
            height = 450,
            root,
            rootDepth,
            x,
            y,
            arc,
            middleArcLine,
            middleAngle,
            color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
            maxRadius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2) - 5;

            const partition = d3.partition();
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // SVG-Element
            let svg = d3.select('#' + i_region_static_id).append('svg')
                            .style('width', width)
                            .style('height', height)
                            .attr('viewBox', `${-width / 2} ${-height / 2} ${width} ${height}`)
                            .on('dblclick', d => {
                                if (event.detail === 2) focusOn() // Double click
                            });
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // X-Scale
            x = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .range([0, 2 * Math.PI])
                    .clamp(true);

            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Y-Scale
            y = d3.scaleSqrt()
                    .range([maxRadius * .1, maxRadius]);

            //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Text-fit constant
            const textFits = d => {
                    const CHAR_SPACE = 6;

                    const deltaAngle = x(d.x1) - x(d.x0);
                    const r = Math.max(0, (y(d.y0) + y(d.y1)) / 2);
                    const perimeter = r * deltaAngle;

                    return d.data.name.length * CHAR_SPACE < perimeter;
            };

            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Create Arc generator
            arc = d3.arc()
                .startAngle(d => x(d.x0))
                .endAngle(d => x(d.x1))
                .innerRadius(d => Math.max(0, y(d.y0)))
                .outerRadius(d => Math.max(0, y(d.y1)))

            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            middleArcLine = d => {
                const halfPi = Math.PI / 2;
                const angles = [x(d.x0) - halfPi, x(d.x1) - halfPi];
                const r = Math.max(0, (y(d.y0) + y(d.y1)) / 2);

                const middleAngle = (angles[1] + angles[0]) / 2;
                const invertDirection = middleAngle > 0 && middleAngle < Math.PI; // On lower quadrants write text ccw
                if (invertDirection) {
                    angles.reverse();
                }

                const path = d3.path();
                path.arc(0, 0, r, angles[0], angles[1], invertDirection);
            return path.toString();
            }

            //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Check if node in depth
            function maxDepth(d) {
            if (rootDepth == undefined) { // If user clicks next to sun = root undefined
                rootDepth = 0;
            }
            return ((d.depth - rootDepth) < 2);
            }

            //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            function focusOn(d = {
                    x0: 0,
                    x1: 1,
                    y0: 0,
                    y1: 1
            }) {
            // Reset to top-level if no data point specified

            // Activate top-level node if no data point specified 
            if (d.data == undefined) {
                svg.selectAll(".slice")
                .filter(d => d.parent == undefined && d.children != undefined)
                .each(function(d) {
                    activateNode(d);
                });
            }

            root = d; // Root-node
            rootDepth = root.depth; // Root node depth for maxDepth(d)

            const transition = svg.transition()
                .duration(750)
                .tween('scale', () => {
                const xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x0, d.x1]),
                    yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y0, 1]);
                return t => {
                    x.domain(xd(t));
                    y.domain(yd(t));
                };
                });

            transition.selectAll('.slice')
                .attr('display', d => maxDepth(d) ? null : 'none'); // Display nodes only in depth for transition

            transition.selectAll('path.main-arc')
                .filter(d => maxDepth(d))
                .attrTween('d', d => () => arc(d));

            transition.selectAll('path.hidden-arc')
                .filter(d => maxDepth(d))
                .attrTween('d', d => () => middleArcLine(d));

            transition.selectAll('text')
                .filter(d => maxDepth(d))
                .attrTween('display', d => () => textFits(d) ? null : 'none'); // Display text only in depth

            moveStackToFront(d);

            // Foreground nodes -> inner nodes higher than outer nodes 
            function moveStackToFront(elD) {
                svg.selectAll('.slice').filter(d => d === elD)
                .each(function(d) {
                    this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
                    if (d.parent) {
                    moveStackToFront(d.parent);
                    }
                })
            }
            }

            //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Initialize and Update sun 
            function sun(pData) {
                root = d3.hierarchy(pData); //set data

                root.sum(d =>
                    (d.children == undefined) ? ((d.size == undefined) ? 1 : d.size) : 0 //parent value defined by childrens values
                );

                const slice = svg.selectAll('g.slice')
                    .data(
                    partition(root)
                    .descendants(),
                    function(d) { return d.data.name; }
                    );

                //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // Enter Section
                const newSlice = slice.enter()
                                        .append('g').attr('class', 'slice')
                                        .attr('display', d => d.depth < 2 ? null : 'none') // Hide levels lower depth
                                        .on('dblclick', d => {focusOn(d);})

                newSlice.append('path')
                            .attr('class', 'main-arc')
                            .style('fill', d => (d.data.color == undefined) ? color((d.children ? d : d.parent).data.name) : d.data.color) //set source color, otherwise default color
                            .attr('d', arc);

                newSlice.append('path')
                        .attr('class', 'hidden-arc')
                        .attr('id', (_, i) => `hiddenArc${i}`)
                        .attr('d', middleArcLine);

                const text = newSlice.append('text')
                        .attr('display', d => textFits(d) ? null : 'none'); // Hide text on lower levels


                text.append('textPath')
                        .attr('startOffset', '50%')
                        .attr('xlink:href', (_, i) => `#hiddenArc${i}`)
                        .text(d => d.data.name) // Set text in sector 
                        .attr('fill', d => 'black');
                
                // Update Section
                slice.select('path')
                        .attr('class', 'main-arc')
                        .style('fill', d => (d.data.color == undefined) ? color((d.children ? d : d.parent).data.name) : d.data.color)
                        .each(function(d) {
                            this.x0 = d.x;
                            this.dx0 = d.dx;
                        })
                        .transition().duration(500)
                        .attr("d", arc);
                
                slice.select('.hidden-arc')
                        .attr('class', 'hidden-arc')
                        .attr('id', (_, i) => `hiddenArc${i}`)
                        .each(function(d) {
                            this.x0 = d.x;
                            this.dx0 = d.dx;
                        })
                        .transition().duration(500)
                        .attr('d', middleArcLine);

                slice.select('text')
                        .attr('display', d => textFits(d) ? null : 'none');
                
                slice.select('textPath')
                        .attr('startOffset', '50%')
                        .attr('xlink:href', (_, i) => `#hiddenArc${i}`)
                        .transition().duration(500)
                        .text(d => d.data.name) // Set text in sector 
                        .attr('fill', d => 'black');

                // Delete Section
                slice.exit().transition().duration(500).style("fill-opacity", 0.2).remove();
            }

            //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            sun(data1)

            let i = 0;
            d3.interval(() => {
            if (i++ % 2 === 0) {
                console.log("data2")
                sun(data2);
            } else {
                console.log("data1")
                sun(data1);
            }

            }, 4000)
```

```css
.slice {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slice .main-arc {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.slice .hidden-arc {
  fill: none;
}

.slice text {
  pointer-events: none;
  text-anchor: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="sunburst"></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3fc" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

**EDIT:**
With the help of the people below, I have now managed to create an update function with a transition.

The update works, but now I get the error message " attribute d: Unexpected end of attribute. Expected number, "....."" several times.

I have updated my code with the new update function.

Comment: use `let` instead of `var` when defining your variables, `const` is fine

Comment: Hi, good advice. I will correct that right away.

Comment: Which "section" of the chart do you want deleted, "Topic C", "Topic A" , "Topic B", "TOPICS", or updated as those "slice" in the HTML are generated and the order can change?

Comment: Based on Data1 and Data2, "TOPIC 3" with its children must be deleted during the update and added again after the next update.

Comment: I suggest you just rerender the entire d3 chart when you change the data, so just wrap your code into a function and then call it with the data like `renderPieChart(data1);` it will be simpliler and be quicker

Comment: something like this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deanvangreunen/r4afvkwz/2/), only issue is that the transition isn't smooth

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I had this approach as a solution before, but the transition is not so smooth. I hoped to be able to solve it differently to get a nice transition. Is there no option or are others worse for performance reasons?

Comment: an alternative solution would be to create an image of the chart using d3 and then taking that image, displaying it above the chart, then changing the data, then using js, reduce the opacity of the image, so it will give this transition like affect. this would give like a blur effect, you will just need to insert the image of the chart above the actual chart, you could use this [to make an image](https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng) or you could try another library

Comment: gen chart first time, before changing data, make image of the chart, display image above chart, change the data using d3, then using js decrease the opacity of the image, then remove it, repeat when data changes.

Comment: Hmm... that sounds very complicated, I'll give it a try. But for that I need to improve my knowledge of d3.js. But thanks for the advice. :)

Comment: How does the enter/update/exit cycle know which nodes to remove? In the absence of any identifying criteria it uses the index of each datum in the array, so if your initial data array has 7 items and your second has 6, the 7th item is removed as it is now excess, regardless of which datum you have removed from the array. You need to use the second parameter for the .data method to identify each node, eg:  `.data( partition(root).descendants(), function(d) { return d.data.name; } );`

Comment: This allows D3 to associate each datum with a specific element by a means other than index - note, it must be a string value